# Spring JPA Query returns Null instead of List

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have an `@Entity Video` having a *one-to-many* relation with a `List<Tag> tags` as one of its fields. I use the following `@Repository` using *Spring Data* to get the most popular tags:

```
@Repository
public interface TagRepository extends CrudRepository<Tag, Integer>{
    @Query("SELECT t FROM Tag t WHERE (SELECT SUM(v.views) FROM Video v WHERE t MEMBER OF v.tags) > 0")
    public List<Tag> findMostViewedTags(int maxTags);
}
```

The *Query* is processed and considered valid by *Spring*, I tested the generated *SQL* vs my database locally and it returned 2 *Tags*. In my Code however, I receive the value *Null* when I call the method findMostViewedTags(100).

The Query lookup strategy is the default "CREATE_IF_NOT_FOUND".

1. If there are no results found, should the method return an empty list or *Null*? My desired behavior is to receive an empty list.
2. Why does the method call return `Null` instead of a `List<Tag>` with size() 2?

Comment: `maxTags` isn't used or that isn't the query you are actually executing.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

1. The normal behavior is indeed returning an empty list if no results are found. If a `List<Object>` is the return value of the method in the defined interface, the method should never return `Null`.
2. The problem is that a parameter is given to the method and is not used anywhere in the *Query*. For some reason *Spring* decides to return a *Null* in that case. Solution: remove the unused parameter or use the parameter in the *Query*.

Comment: The "Solution" should include raise a bug on Spring to better cater for that situation

Comment: @Vjeetje is it specified anywhere in the docs that it returns an empty list if no results are found? I cant find it

Comment: @osmingo Here you go.. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.nullability

`Repository methods returning collections, collection alternatives, wrappers, and streams are guaranteed never to return null but rather the corresponding empty representation`

Answer (score 7):

I have experienced similar problem. The cause was that I was using Mockito and have not correctly mocked the data with `when()`.